# Jquery each loop not getting the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
testArray =[[ 'text1', 'text2', 'text3' ],
    [ 'question',
      'correct answer',
      'second answer',
      'third answer',
      'fourth answer' ],
    [ 'question',
      'correct answer',
      'second answer',
      'third answer',
      'fourth answer',
      'fifth answer',
      'sixth answer' ]];

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id = "passage"></div>
<div id = "question"></div>
<div id = "answers"></div>

<script>

$.each(testArray[1].slice(1), function (i) {
    $("#answers").append("<p>" + testArray[1][i] + "</p>");
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I ran this, I was expecting the last each loop to loop through the elements from `testArray[1][1]` to `testArray[1][4]`. For some reason though, it's only going up to `testArray[1][3]`. Does anyone know what the problem is?

EDIT:

I did this and it somehow worked for what I wanted to do (start at the index-1 element and loop to the end):

```
$.each(testArray[1].slice(1), function (i) {
    $("#answers").append("<p>" + testArray[1][i + 1] + "</p>");
});
```

Not sure how/why this works though.

Comment: `slice` removes the last element. You don't need to use slice. Just remove that and it will work.

Comment: I wanted to use slice in order to remove the first element (index 0) and start the loop from the second element (index 1).

Comment: to remove first element, you need to use `shift()` or `splice(0,1)`

Comment: Hey sorry, I misunderstood your question in the beginning. I changed my answer. Somehow jQuery uses the reference of the object or something. I used the ES6 forEach method and it works fine.

Comment: @Milan That changes the array permanently, which is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed weird. I tried it with the ES6 version and it works just fine:

```
  testArray[ 1 ].slice( 1 ).forEach( item => {
    $("#answers").append("<p>" + item + "</p>");
  } );
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

The problem is you're passing the sliced array to $.each, but inside the callback you're indexing the original array.

The array $.each recieves is ['correct answer', 'second answer','third answer', 'fourth answer'], but inside it's getting your values from testArray when you really want it from the array you're passing in. One solution is to just use the value that's passed in as the second argument to the callback function.

```js
testArray =[[ 'text1', 'text2', 'text3' ],
    [ 'question',
      'correct answer',
      'second answer',
      'third answer',
      'fourth answer' ],
    [ 'question',
      'correct answer',
      'second answer',
      'third answer',
      'fourth answer',
      'fifth answer',
      'sixth answer' ]];

$.each(testArray[1].slice(1), function (i, value) {
    $("#answers").append("<p>" + value + "</p>");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id = "passage"></div>
<div id = "question"></div>
<div id = "answers"></div>
```

Comment: I wanted to use slice to get rid of the first element... how would I do that?

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a simple `if` condition, below is the code:

```js
testArray = [
  ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'],
  ['question',
    'correct answer',
    'second answer',
    'third answer',
    'fourth answer'
  ],
  ['question',
    'correct answer',
    'second answer',
    'third answer',
    'fourth answer',
    'fifth answer',
    'sixth answer'
  ]
];

$.each(testArray[1], function(i) {
  if (i > 0)
    $("#answers").append("<p>" + testArray[1][i] + "</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="passage"></div>
<div id="question"></div>
<div id="answers"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, so that changes your question too. Secondly, efforts should not be down-voted.

Comment: Added an `if` condition to ignore the first element of an array without affecting the original `array`